# Element in JSON of type date is being sent as timestamp instead of date

Tags: json, web-services, jackson, restful-architecture

I am converting the json received from database to object User.class using Objectmapper,class structure as follows

```
@XmlRootElement        
public class User {
    public User() {
        super();
    }
    @XmlElement
    private String username=null;

    @XmlElement
    private Feedbacks feedbacks=null;

   //getter setter....

}
```

User has an instance of Feedbacks class which in turn has Arraylist< Feedback>

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Feedbacks {

    public Feedbacks() {

    }
    @XmlElement
    private ArrayList<Feedback> FeedbackList=new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Feedback> getFeedbackList() {
    return FeedbackList;
    }

    public void setFeedbackList(ArrayList<Feedback> FeedbackList) {
    this.FeedbackList = FeedbackList;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Feedback {     

    private String feedback=null;
    //private String timeStamp=null;
    /*@JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer.class); */
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
    private Date feedbackDate;

    public Feedback (){} 

}
```

Sample json that i retrieve from db is:

```
{
"userName":"Test",
"feedbacks":{
 "feedbackTOList":[
  {
   "feedback":"Please select appropriate value..1",
   "timeStamp":"03/01/2000 14:52"
  },
  {
  "feedback":"Please select appropriate value..2",
  "timeStamp":"03/01/2018 13:50"
  },
  {
  "feedback":"Please select appropriate value..3",
  "timeStamp":"02/01/2018 10:52"
  }

  ]
  }
}
```

Json to object conversion and sorting the list of feedback based on date:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setDateFormat(formatter);
    userObject= mapper.readValue(jsonPayload, User.class);
    Collections.sort(user.getFeedbacks().getFeedbackList(), new 
    Comparator<Feedback>() {
        public int compare(Feedback f1, Feedback f2) {
            if (f1.getTimeStamp() == null || f2.getTimeStamp() == null)
                return 0;
            return (f2.getTimeStamp().compareTo(f1.getTimeStamp()));
            }
        });
```

The issue is when angular UI consumes the object from rest service,instead of Date `(Wed Aug 01 16:20:00 EDT 2018])` the timestamp value is being sent as `timeStamp=1533154800000`.

My question is how do i send the string in given format or atleast date object but not timestamp?

So far i tried  `@JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")`,custom date deserializer but no luck(by referring many other posts on stackoverflow,sites),can some one please let me know what mistake am i making?

Comment: have you tried to disable timestamp serialization? You could try it with: `mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);`

Comment: That option was in mind,but since i am using jackson 1.8, `mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) is not available`.

Comment: Or Is any higher version of Jackson compatible with jersery 1.10,would there be any issues any compatibility or dependency issues?

Comment: Also tried    `mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);`    `mapper.writer(dateFormatter);` with jackson 2.0.2